# How can I unzip file encrypted with algorithm other than PKZIP in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, encryption, zip

I want to unzip archives protected by password with Python 3. I know the password, but it seems that there are several encryption algorithms within zip standard.

First, I create a zip archive with standard Ubuntu's Archive Manager 3.16.5, using password "1". Then I run the following code:

```
import zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')
zip_file.extractall(pwd=b'1')
```

As a result, I get `RuntimeError: ('Bad password for file', <ZipInfo filename='contents.txt' compress_type=99 filemode='-rw-rw-r--' external_attr=0x8020 file_size=40 compress_size=60>)`.

When I run Archive Manager for decompression, it works fine. However, once I try `unzip`, it fails to do the job:

```
$ unzip -P 1 archive.zip 
Archive:  archive.zip
    skipping: contents.txt            need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)
```

As far as I understand, the problem is that `unzip` uses [PKZIP](https://www.academia.edu/348210/PKZIP_Algorithm) algorithm, while `libarchive` widely used `7zip` and Archive Manager usually prefers AES for encryption (and have a good security reason).

So, how can I choose algorithm for unzipping in Python? Or should I take no care of the zip format itself and find any AES decryptor and somehow connect it to `unzip` later?

I considered using `7zip` within a bash call, but it brings further problems with interaction with the OS (what if executing machine does not have one?). I also looked up `libarchive` port to Python 3 (namely, `python3-libarchive-c` package) - it is developed separately from C implementation and does not support encryption/decryption as for today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pyzipper](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipper/) library for unpacking AES-encrypted zip files.